# How To Align package.json and package-lock.json When Dependency Versions Are Out of Sync?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

**Whats Happening**

In Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
    ...
}
```

Run `npm install`

in package-lock.json:

```
"node-sass": {
    "version": "4.13.1",
    ...
}
```

**What I've Tried**

**1.**

Deleting:

- package-lock.json
- node_modules dir

Then running `npm install`

**2.**

Deleting:

- package-lock.json
- node_modules dir

Then running `npm install --cache /temp/empty-cache`

**3.**

Deleting:

- package-lock.json
- node_modules dir

Then running `npm update`

Result: node-sass is not detected as updatable

**4.**

running `npm install node-sass@4.13.1`

This obviously works at syncing them both back up, but doesn't feel right as this could be happening to other dependencies without me knowing.

**Questions**

- How do I get package.json and package-lock back in sync, without manually installing 4.13.1?
- [Bonus] Why does 4.13.1 always get installed and used by package-lock.json?
- [Bonus] Why does node-sass no get identified as needing an update?

**[EDIT]**

Would still love an answer for this, if anyone has one that doesn't involve manually updating the dependency

Answer (score 7):

this solved my issue

npm install --package-lock-only

Comment: Hi Blanché Carstens; this is a good answer, but it would be better if you could briefly explain why this command is what's needed.

Answer (score 5):

Those dependencies are exactly what you have configured:

in your `package.json` you defined `^4.13.0`, the `^` means that you are fine installing the most recent version of that module with the major version of 4.
So when you run `npm install` you will install all the dependencies that match that [semver range](https://semver.npmjs.com/).
You can go deeper in [semver](https://devhints.io/semver).

If you want to lock the version you need to write `"node-sass": "4.13.0"` in your `package.json` and recreate the `package-lock.json`

Moreover, to install what is in the `package-lock.json` you need to run [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html). If you run `npm install` you are updating your dependencies in your lock file (that will be updated)

---

> How align package.json and package-lock.json where dependency versions are out of sync?

Regenerate the package-lock

Example:

```
npm init --yes
npm init fastify@2.0.0
// now package-lock has 2.0.0
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
// now package-lock has 2.0.0 still
rm package-lock.json
npm install fastify@2.5.0 --no-save
npm install
// now package-lock has 2.5.0 (the version is loaded by node_modules tree)
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
// now package-lock has 2.11.0
```

So, if your files are out of sync "something" run the installation without using the lock file

Comment: Hi Manuel, my understanding of ```^``` is that the dependency is upgradable but that an ```npm update``` must be done to begin using the latest version. I've just tested running ```npm install``` in a project with a dependency that is 1 patch(^3.4.3) version behind the latest in both ```package-lock``` and ```package``` and the version installed to node_modules was not the latest (3.4.4).

Comment: what version of npm?

Comment: 6.x, (locally: 6.13.4)

Comment: edit the answer, if you want to keep a version you need to lock dep in package.json and run `npm outdate` when needed to check the latest version

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem as well, but only on the build server. I tried everything and in the meantime stumbled multiple times upon the hint that npm install and npm ci must be executed with the exact same flags. It was, at least I thought it would be.
In the end, the problem was that my local environment had in its `.npmrc` file the `legacy-peer-deps` parameter set to true which caused both commands executing correctly on my machine but not npm ci on the build server.